# How to modify a set of concatenate traces in one file to a set of

Tags: python, numpy

I have a set of traces in one folder  `Folder_Traces`:

```
  Trace1.npy
  Trace2.npy
  Trace3.npy
  Trace4.npy
  ...
```

In my code, I must concatenate all traces and put them in one file.Each trace is a table. The big file where I put all my file is a table containing a set of tables.  This file looks like this: `All_Traces=[[Trace1],[Trace2],[Trace3],...[Tracen]]`

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

sbox=( 0x63,0x7c,0x77,0x7b,0xf2,0x6b..........) 
hw = [bin(x).count("1") for x in range(256)]

print (sbox)
print ([hw[s] for s in sbox])


# Start calculating template
# 1: load data
tempTraces = np.load(r'C:\\Users\\user\\2016.06.01-09.41.16_traces.npy')
tempPText  = np.load(r'C:\\Users\\user\\2016.06.01-09.41.16_textin.npy')
tempKey    = np.load(r'C:\\Users\\user\\2016.06.01-09.41.16_keylist.npy')

print (tempPText)
print (len(tempPText))
print (tempKey)
print (len(tempKey))
plt.plot(tempTraces[0])
plt.show()

tempSbox = [sbox[tempPText[i][0] ^ tempKey[i][0]] for i in range(len(tempPText))] 

print (sorted(tempSbox))
```

So, what I need is to use all my trace files without concatenation, because concatenation causes many memory problems. So what I need is to change this line: `tempTraces = np.load(r'C:\\Users\\user\\2016.06.01-09.41.16_traces.npy')`  by the path for my folder directly then load each trace and make the necessary analysis. So, How to resolve that please?

Comment: have you tried replacing `[sbox[tempPText[i][0] ^ tempKey[i][0]] for i in range(len(tempPText))]` with generator comprehension `(sbox[tempPText[i][0] ^ tempKey[i][0]] for i in range(len(tempPText)))`?

Comment: @AzatIbrakov It works for the both solution, but what I need is to change tempTraces = np.load(r'C:\\Users\\user\\2016.06.01-09.41.16_traces.npy') by the path to the folder directly.